# Behaviour of 64 bit variable arithmetic operations on 32 bit machine

Tags: java, cpu, 32bit-64bit

How CPU cycles will behave in case of arithmetic operations ?
like addition of two 64bit integers

Edit:

Can we have 64 bit variable in 32 bit machine? -- off course yes At the time of asking question I was confused so edited this now.

Comment: Yes, of course you can. Unless you've got a compelling case where you're seeing a performance issue through this though (highly unlikely), then CPU cycle behaviour *doesn't matter.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, for example, a java `long` is a 64 bit two's complement integer. The CPU cycles will vary depending on the processor chipset and different JDK/JRE implementations, but obviously it's going to be more cycles than for a 64 bit machine. I'd recommend you conduct experiments on your target hardware and JDK/JRE.

Comment: +1 addition is about 2x, multiplication is about 4x and division is much slower and varies based on the CPU.

Comment: thanks @PeterLawrey  Basically I was thinking in terms of word tearing , like in java if I add 2 long (64 bit) Integer variables on 32 bit OS  in multithreading env then possiblity of atmoic operation is on 1 bit or 32 bits will be operated in one atmoic operation?

Comment: @user2922515 It is likely to be processor dependant.  On x86 systems, it is hard to find a true 32-bit processor i.e. one which cannot do 64-bit operations.  If you use an older ARM processor they don't have as well defined memory model and I would expect this is possibly a problem.  Java didn't always specify 64-bit operation as atomic, but on x86 systems they were.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Doesn it means java doesn't specify some 64 bit operation will be atomic or not ?  If we want to guarantee atomic operation then we need to use Atmoic classes.

Comment: @Vipin reads and writes on a 64-bit JVM are atomic, but not a read and a write. For more complex atomic operations you need the AtomicLong class.